# C# - How can i sum two values based on list of codes

Tags: c#

When the user enter with the codes i can show the unit price, like this:

```
    double peca1 = 15.10;
    double peca2 = 15.10;
    double peca12 = 5.30;
    double peca13 = 15.30;
    double peca16 = 5.10;
    double peca161 = 5.20;

        private void cbCodPeca1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (cbCodPeca1.Text == "1")
        {
            tbValor1.Text = String.Format("{0:C}", peca1);
        }
        else if (cbCodPeca1.Text == "2")
        {
            tbValor1.Text = String.Format("{0:C}", peca2);
        }
        else if (cbCodPeca1.Text == "12")
        {
            tbValor1.Text = String.Format("{0:C}", peca12);
        }
        else if (cbCodPeca1.Text == "13")
        {
            tbValor1.Text = String.Format("{0:C}", peca13);
        }
        else if (cbCodPeca1.Text == "16")
        {
            tbValor1.Text = String.Format("{0:C}", peca16);
        }
        else if (cbCodPeca1.Text == "161")
        {
            tbValor1.Text = String.Format("{0:C}", peca161);
        }
    }
```

[Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tXu5.png)

But how can i sum the first code (price * amount) +  second code (price * amount)?

Exemple:

Input 1
12 1 5.30
Input 2
16 2 5.10

Output
15.50

Comment: Your first step is to change the way you store the values, by using a dictionary instead of hard-coded variables. See duplicate for that. Then you can parse the input to retrieve the values as needed and perform whatever computation you like.

Comment: Store the record when the user enters it. So essentially, have a “private string userEntry;” and when the user enters the text set userEntry = entered. Also, look into case switch. You can do switch(cbCodPeca1.Text) { case “1”:  //do work break; } much cleaner!